# JessTab: Finding the youngest person in family ontology

Tags: protege, jess

I am using the [family ontology][1] to test Jess rules. Everything works fine unless manipulating data with Jess built-in functions e.g. min and max. I have designed the following rule:

```
(defrule print_people_min_age 
(object  (https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/family_example.owl#age ?a)) 
   => 
(printout t "Min age " (min ?a) crlf))
```

The rule compiles well, but I am not getting the desired output. It outputs me ages of each person in the ontology. I tried to put the min function in the LHS but it results in error.

[1]: Family Ontology https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/attachment/wiki/AddingRuleWithJessTab/family_example_for_rules.owl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `(min <numeric-expresion>+)` and `(max <numeric-expresion>+)` are meant to be applied to a number of arguments - you are calling it with just one argument. The rule fires once for each object, and the minimum of that single age is - that age.

This rule illustrates how to find a minimum:

```
(defrule print_people_min_age 
(object  (https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/family_example.owl#age ?a1))
(not (object (https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/family_example.owl#age ?a2&:(< ?a2 ?a1))))
=> 
(printout t "Min age " ?a1 crlf))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately this gives maximum value of age property. I modified the arrow > to < and it gives the result. I think its because of the not operator.

Comment: Sorry but that was a simple mistake; fixed. The not is OK - just the thing that makes it work, min or max.